# New / overriding language engines in RStudio Notebooks

Tags: r, rstudio, rnotebook

I'm supposed to be able to register new / changes knitr engines using:

```
knitr::knit_engines$set(sql = function(options) {
    stop("At least I'm being used")
    NULL
})
```

but when I use this in an RStudio notebook, my "special" sql engine isn't getting invoked, it's still calling the "default" one.

What's the magic for getting this to work under RStudio?

Comment: You might want to file this as a bug report at https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin.  Issue raised with reproducible example - https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3749